# norm of (sub)stochastic matrix

Tags: norms, matrix-analysis

Is there any bounds for the norm of sub-stochastic matrix? (But it's not doubly stochastic matrix, I mean only the row sum is less than 1, while the column sum may not.

Comment: Which norm are you interested in? If talking about the norm induced by the infinity norm over the state space  ($\|x\| = \max\limits_{i}|x_i|$) then in general you can only say that for the sub-stochastic matrix $A$ you have $\|A\| := \sup\limits_{\|x\| =1}\|Ax\| \leq 1$. Further bounds depend on the structure of $A$.

Comment: I mean spectral norm. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A useful and easy to compute bound is given by the reasonably well-known relation (see e.g., [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence))
\begin{equation*}
\|A\| \le \sqrt{\|A\|_\infty \|A\|_1}
\end{equation*}
between the spectral norm, and the induced $1$ and $\infty$ norms of an arbitrary matrix $A$.

*Corollary:* If $A$ is elementwise nonnegative and row-stochastic, then
$\|A\| \le \sqrt{\|A\|_1}$.

**Note**
For some refinements of the first inequality mentioned above, please refer to [this paper by V. Nikiforov](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702722).